# android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO default email chooser

Tags: android, email, sendto

How can I send a e-mail in android app without chooser? I want that user set a default email client once and the app just use this email client until the user change your settings!

the idea is press button send in my app and the msg will send it without chooser

tks

Comment: The user can do this on their own, without any involvement from you, if you do *not* use `createChooser()` when sending the email. They will be able to designate a default email client to use for similar sorts of requests in the future (e.g., click "Always" instead of "Just once" on Android 4.0+).

Comment: tks @CommonsWare, this solve my problem, how can I change this topic to solved topic?

Comment: I converted my comment into an answer -- you can check the checkmark to the left of the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The user can do this on their own, without any involvement from you, if you do *not* use `createChooser()` when sending the email. They will be able to designate a default email client to use for similar sorts of requests in the future (e.g., click "Always" instead of "Just once" on Android 4.0+).

`createChooser()` is specifically for scenarios where the default choice might be incorrect. That's typically less of an issue with `ACTION_SENDTO` than it is for `ACTION_SEND`, where you see `createChooser()` used more.